# C++ compiler issue (?): can't pass arguments to functions in separate class files

Tags: c++, arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I recently started working on an interpreter in C++, but I got annoyed that vectors or arrays could not be passed to external class methods no matter what I tried and so I deleted everything I had worked on. As it turns out, I can't pass even an *int* to another class. I decided to give C++ another chance before resorting to C or Java, but the compiler still doesn't work as I would expect. Maybe I'm forgetting something simple about C++, as I haven't used it in a while, but this seems simple enough. My problem is: I can't pass arguments to methods in other classes when they're not defined in the same file. Here's what I'm trying to do:

**Main: main.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h"

int main() {
    MyClass test;
    int n = test.add(25, 30);
    return n;
}
```

**Header: myclass.h**

```
class MyClass {
public:
    int add(int a, int b);
};
```

**Class implementation: myclass.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h"

int MyClass::add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Compiling this with `g++ main.cpp` yields

> /tmp/ccAZr6EY.o: In function `main':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to`MyClass::add(int, int)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What the heck am I doing wrong? Also, the compiler yells at me for the same thing even if my functions aren't parameterized, so it must be a problem with the header.

Any help is much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: You have to link the implementation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: I'm sure this question must be a duplicate.

Comment: Feel free to delete it - wouldn't want the stackoverflow server to crash 'cause of my 60kb of data... But thanks Chris - I thought of doing that, but I don't remember having to.

Comment: `g++ -c myclass.cpp ; g++ main.cpp myclass.o`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile both files

```
g++ main.cpp myclass.cpp
```

If you only compile main.cpp, the compiler finds the declaration of `MyClass::add` in your header but the linker later fails to find an implementation of `MyClass::add` to jump to.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you. Can't believe I thought it would magically find the implementation... I must be in Java land.